# What's the Statute of Limitations on chat bans?

Tags: support, chat, moderator-tools

So I've been chat banned twice AFAIK:

- When I was quite new to chat, I once asked a mod to chat ban me for a few minutes *for science* to see what it was like to be banned from chat.
  (For anyone wanting to know: it looks like you're not logged in without the possibility to log in)
- I posted the "Feyenoord Kid Finger" image as a response to someone from Rotterdam which got me another ban for a few minutes as the person I directed this message to told the mod it's a **world-famous picture** <sub><sup>in The Netherlands</sup></sub> and it's a cute, though a bit rude pic *and extremely funny*.
  (For anyone wanting to know: Google Image search it, it's one of the top-10 hits and it'll be quite obvious which one I'm talking about)

And the question is: *How long will it take for these 2 bans to age away and die and my chat ban score to become 0 again???*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chat suspensions never go away.  (Source: I'm a moderator and I can see them.)  However, two things might make you feel better:

- Automatic bans from validated flags are standardized; they increase in length if *clustered*, but a chat ban from years ago doesn't affect how long the system kicks you out.
- For manual bans, moderators see the history including the dates.  I can't speak for every moderator, but I think most treat repeat offenses differently depending on whether the previous one was two hours ago or two years ago.

Comment: Is it possible to ask that an employee remove the "for science" ban from one's history?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog - that's only happened once that I'm aware of; when Shog chat-banned Undo (as a mod) for... a year+, I think. That doesn't show in Undo's history. Otherwise, we depend on annotations to mark "science" suspensions.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Given the subjective/manual nature of mod suspensions, I'm pretty sure a "for science" suspension has no negative effect if it's labeled properly.

Comment: No, but the moderator who did it could annotate the account to explain what happened.  (Manual unsuspensions automatically show up in the history, though, so science tends to stand out.)

Comment: I have no problem with you showing my chat bans in your answe if that's not considered a trade secret by the powers that be ...